# How to substitute multiple alphanumeric characters in R?

Tags: r

In a dataframe `DF` which is as follows:

```
DF$Values

Values
B1
A
A2
B
B2
A1
C2
C1
C
```

I want to substitute `A2,B,B2` as `Group1`, `B1,C2,C1,C` as `Group2`, and `A1, A` as `Group3` and so on. Such that the output data looks like this

```
Values
Group2
Group3
Group1
Group1
Group1
Group3
Group2
Group2
Group2
```

I tried using `gsub()` but it is not working properly for me, as the code 
`gsub("A1|A", "Group3" ,DF)` replaces `A2` with `Group32`

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating factor levels for each group?

```
df$Values <- as.factor(df$Values)
levels(df$Values) <- list(Group1= c("A2","B","B2"), Group2= c("B1","C2","C1","C"),
                                                    Group3 = c("A1", "A"))
df$Values
#[1] Group2 Group3 Group1 Group1 Group1 Group3 Group2 Group2 Group2
#Levels: Group1 Group2 Group3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do an `ifelse` with `%in%` (it is not clear if there are any specific patterns from the OP's post) to recode the elements to different one.

```
with(DF, ifelse(Values %in% c("A2", "B", "B2"), "Group1",
       ifelse(Values %in% c("B1", "C2", "C1", "C"), "Group2", "Group3")))
#[1] "Group2" "Group3" "Group1" "Group1" "Group1" "Group3" "Group2" "Group2" "Group2"
```